# Phonegap not sending http only cookie in requests after login

Tags: cordova, cookies, sails.js

I have my APIs running in Sails JS, which is marking my cookies as HTTPOnly. After logging in, in subsequent requests to the server, phonegap app is not sending the cookies due to which my app always throws a 403 error.

Is there a way to tell phonegap that it needs to pass the cookies marked httponly? Or shouldn't it be the default behaviour?

Comment: PhoneGap does not handle this, it is the native webview. You will have to check the spec for the webview you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know that cookies are not supported in phonegap till now, so the only way in your case is to send params manually in your requests.
Also take care to your access policy to allow all urls, update your config.xml file with the following code:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Are you referring to a code like <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />. This code already exists in my res/xml/config.xml, but still it does not works. The cookies are not being sent to the APIs due to which requests throw 403 errors.